# Export layout to in memory PDF

Tags: arcpy, export, pdf, data-driven-pages

I want to make a Data Driven export to PDF of the layout using arcpy, and later add to that PDF extra pages from PDFs from my local computer.

My problem is that I don't actually want to make the exports of the PDFs on my computer using the *arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF* , I would only want to store that page (the data driven layout) in the memory, and later on, add the extra pages.

I use this code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0]

for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount+1):
    pageName = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue(nameField)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"C:\TEST\tempExport{}.pdf".format(pageNum)) # This is the temporary export that I want to be stored in memory, not on my local machine
    pdfDoc = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(r"C:\TEST\FinalPDF{}.pdf".format(pageNum))
    pdfDoc.appendPages(r"C:\TEST\tempExport{}.pdf".format(pageNum))
    pdfDoc.appendPages(r"C:\TEST\local{}.pdf".format(pageNum))
    pdfDoc.saveAndClose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that there is anything in ArcPy that will help you here.

Using `arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate`(`PDF file`) it is possible to copy a PDF file from disk into memory and then append pages to it in memory.

However, there is nothing to enable writing the output from `arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF` to memory.

If such functionality is important to you then I recommend researching/submitting an ArcGIS Idea for it.